# http inbound gateway path url mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

i have two int-http:inbound-gateway  with path as mentioned below.when i call

```
http://localhost:8080/XYZ/ABCService/query  -- i expected to call http:inbound-gateway with id ="XYZ"

http://localhost:8080/ABCService/query  - i expected to call http:inbound-gateway with id ="default"
```

but what happing in its not consistence when i give request to `http://localhost:8080/XYZ/ABCService/query`
 it is calling "default" gateway.i understand it because of the path /*Serivce.But i like to know can i give some order or priority or some kind of url mapping  to say always check "XYZ" first then check "default"

I am using DispatcherServlet.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="default"
        path="/*Service/query"
        request-channel="RequestChannel" reply-channel="ResponseChannel"
        supported-methods="POST" reply-timeout="5000" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
        error-channel="ErrorChannel" mapped-request-headers="xyz-*, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>


    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="XYZ"
        path="/XYZ/*Service/query"
        request-channel="RequestChannel" reply-channel="XYZResponseChannel"
        supported-methods="POST" reply-timeout="5000" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
        error-channel="ErrorChannel" mapped-request-headers="xyz-*, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS">
         <int-http:header name="reply-type" expression="'ABC'" />
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

   <int:channel id="ResponseChannel">

    </int:channel>


    <int:header-value-router input-channel="ResponseChannel"
        header-name="reply-type">

        <int:mapping value="ABC" channel="XYZResponseChannel" />
    </int:header-value-router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can elaborate that you really sure that it doesn't work properly?

What I see that both your endpoints have the same config. The dfference is only in the path, but all other attrs are the same.

That means that all your messages independently of `path` will be send to the `RequestChannel`.

I've just tested and eveything works well:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/*path1" request-channel="path"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/foo/*path1" request-channel="fooPath"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Sorry my bad i have i intended to put different reply-channel only by mistake i put same reply-channel.I have edited the correct one in my original message.So the issue i am facing is every other time am getting reply from reply-channel=" ResponseChannel" when i request for http://localhost:8080/XYZ/ABCService/query which expect to from reply-channel="XYZResponseChannel"