# int-http:inbound-gateway same request Channel and different Response channel issue

Tags: spring-integration

i have two int-http:inbound-gateway with path as mentioned below.And points to same request channel but have different reply-channel.

```
 http://localhost:8080/XYZ/ABCService/query  -- i expected to call http:inbound-gateway with id ="XYZ"

    http://localhost:8080/ABCService/query  - i expected to call http:inbound-gateway with id ="default"
```

but what happing in its not consistence when i give request to

```
 http://localhost:8080/XYZ/ABCService/query
```

it is calling "default" gateway other time its calling "XYZ" i.e not consistence. or not sure it may call correctly but instead gives response to different reply-channel ?

I am using DispatcherServlet.Below my spring-integration.xml

```
     <int-http:inbound-gateway id="default"
                path="/*Service/query"
                request-channel="RequestChannel" reply-channel="ResponseChannel"
                supported-methods="POST" reply-timeout="5000" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
                error-channel="ErrorChannel" mapped-request-headers="xyz-*, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS">
                <int-http:header name="reply-type" expression="'DEFAULT'" />
         </int-http:inbound-gateway>


            <int-http:inbound-gateway id="XYZ"
                path="/XYZ/*Service/query"
                request-channel="RequestChannel" reply-channel="XYZExportTransformedChannel"
                supported-methods="POST" reply-timeout="5000" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
                error-channel="ErrorChannel" mapped-request-headers="xyz-*, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS">
                 <int-http:header name="reply-type" expression="'ABC'" />
            </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <!--All endpoints  output chanlle is CommonResonseChannel -->
    <int:channel id="CommonResponseChannel">

        </int:channel>

        <!-- final router -->

          <int:header-value-router input-channel="CommonResponseChannel"
                header-name="reply-type">
                <int:mapping value="DEFAULT" channel="ResponseChannel" />
                <int:mapping value="ABC" channel="XYZResponseChannel" />
            </int:header-value-router>

           <int:channel id="ResponseChannel">

            </int:channel>

     <int:channel id="XYZResponseChannel">

            </int:channel>

<int:transformer input-channel="XYZResponseChannel"
        output-channel="XYZExportTransformedChannel" id="TransformerChannel"
        ref="objToCSVTransformer"></int:transformer>

    <bean class="SomeTransformer"
        id="objToCSVTransformer"></bean>

<int:channel id="XYZExportTransformedChannel" />




    I have opened this question before not not very clear.Not sure how to update that.So opened new one.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [http inbound gateway path url mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540814/http-inbound-gateway-path-url-mapping)

Comment: Yes but not exactly.i am using same request-channel and different response channel.Also Response comes from Endpoint i am redirecting to some other channel.If you help i will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should not configure your reply channels that way; it may cause unpredictable results.

`reply-channel`s are simply bridged to the message `replyChannel` header so it generally will work ok, but it's unpredictable because the bridge is set up when the gateway first receives a message.

Instead, simply omit the `reply-channel` attributes on the gateways and let the framework route the replies directly using the `replyChannel` header.

Instead of your router, configure a "bridge to nowhere" (a `<bridge/>` with  `input-channel= CommonResponseChannel"` and no `output-channel`.

Or simply omit the `output-channel` on the last endpoints (instead of sending to `CommonResponseChannel`).

Comment: Thanks Gary For you Support.

Comment: Sorry if i ask silly questions.what i not understand is if i not configure the reply-channel how it know which response it should give.or can't i  do any modification after Endpoint for the result.i.e i need to send different result based on different path but the endpoints are same ,after getting the results i will redirect to some channel and do some transformation and put result in some channel where its configured as reply-channel for http inbound gateway. pls see int-http:inbound-gateway id="XYZ" in main post

Comment: You can do whatever you want but if you have 2 or more gateways feeding the same flow it's best to leave off the `output-channel` on the last component - the framework knows how to route the reply to the original gateway, using the `replyChannel` message header. The need for an explicit reply channel is rare - only needed if you want to add a wire tap, or make it a pub/sub channel etc.

Comment: In my case am using 2 path "default" and "XYZ".Both routes to SameEndpoint after result comes from Endpoint if its a request for "default"  (as i just want the result same as Endpoint) framework takes care using the replyChannel .But for "XYZ" after results come from the Endpoint i need to transform or change the message and really i need to give new message to "XYZ"  which i put that in channel="XYZResponse" now what will happen ? As framework uses the replyChannel it will gives "XYZ" same result as Endpoint result. The "XYZ" won't get result from channel "XYZResponse".

Comment: What you have should work just fine because you are routing to the correct reply-channel; I just prefer to let the framework handle reply routing. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flows to see what's wrong.

Comment: Really am not able to figure this out.One time response coming from  correct  channel.another time its coming from the output channel of the service activator.While DEBUG logging same issue i can see one time its stops at the service-activators output-channel another time its going to correct reply-channel configured in http inbound.so confused seems only Endpoint's output-channel will be taken care.Not sure how to fix this or its a bug

Comment: I doubt it's a bug; I suggest you update your question with the current configuration and post the log somewhere (gist etc).